# MPAndroidChart Legend labels invisible

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the MPAndroidChart library, it will automatically generate legend labels, then I used `chart.getLegend().setEnable(false)`, it all invisible. How can I do to let some of the labels invisible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LineDataSet can conrtol individual Legends.

```
LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(entryList, "FirstLegend");
```

Inorder to make the legend label invisible , use the below code

```
lineDataSet.setLabel("");
```

Inorder to make the legend form invisible, use the below code

```
lineDataSet.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.NONE);
```